# Using attached properties in a style

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use an attached property for a TextBox style to enable to use of a watermark text. However, I cannot seem to get it working. The project builds fine, but the watermark does not show up. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

WatermarkProperty.cs

```
public class WatermarkProperty
{
  public static string GetWatermark(DependencyObject obj)
  {
     return (string)obj.GetValue(WatermarkProp);
  }

  public static void SetWatermark(DependencyObject obj, string value)
  {
     obj.SetValue(WatermarkProp, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProp =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Watermark", typeof(string), typeof(WatermarkProperty), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp">
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
              <Setter Property="Background">
                 <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush>
                       <VisualBrush.Visual>
                          <Label Content="{Binding Path=(local:WatermarkProperty.Watermark), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Foreground="LightGray" />
                       </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
           </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>

  <TextBox local:WatermarkProperty.Watermark="Testing" Width="200"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a `template` for a `textbox` with `watermark`, you need a style similar to the `style` below (this style has been tested and works):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="myTextBoxStyle">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

                            <Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="PART_InnerGrid"
                              Margin="2">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                          Grid.Column="0"
                                          BorderThickness="0"
                                          IsTabStop="False"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Background="{x:Null}" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="Message"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding local:TextBoxHelper.Watermark}"
                                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                       Visibility="Collapsed"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Opacity="0.6"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="6,2,6,2" />
                                    <ContentControl/>
                                </Grid>
                             </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}"
                                     Value="">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Message"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

And to make this `style` have effect on your `textbox` it takes setting it manually:

```
<TextBox local:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Testing" Width="200" Height="40" Style="{StaticResource myTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

I realized some modifications in its class `WatermarkProperty`. None of the changes affect the functionality of the class, but to follow the naming standard used when you want to create a class of "help" the structure of a `control`. The following new class now called `TextBoxHelper`:

```
public class TextBoxHelper
    {
        public static string GetWatermark(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(WatermarkProperty);
        }

        public static void SetWatermark(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Watermark", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
    }
```

The name of `WatermarkProperty` to `TextBoxHelper` was changed because the class helps the `textbox` control. And also modified the name of the `attached property` to `WatermarkProperty`, so obeying all a standard nomenclature.

Answer (score -1):

You don't use attached properties like that. You just straight up use them as normal XAML properties:

```
<Label local:WatermarkProperty.Watermark="{Binding ...}" />
```

Also, your WatermarkProperty should be static if you want to be a good citizen.